# HTTP Error Handler in Odoo

Tags: odoo, gunicorn

I'm running Odoo 8, which sits on top of gunicorn.  When the web server throws a 500 Internal Server Error I'd like the user to see something besides the default browser page.

**Is there a way to catch and handle HTTP errors in Odoo?**

Answer (score -1):

Always keep backup of your database from your PostgreSQL or pgadmin . When you restart your pc . Just Restore it in odoo . Then there are minimum chances of HTTP internal error ......

The backup of your database also keep user interface of odoo with itself . Try It.

Comment: Not an answer to my question.